# Структура данных для хранения объектов по датам и категориям

Tags: c++, структуры, проектирование

Ломаю голову несколько дней, учу сразу много всего и параллельно пытаюсь что-то писать (пока что на с++). Моя программа должна вести учет расходов. Наиболее часто требуется выводить пользователю информацию о расходах по категориям за каждый день, но в некоторых отчетах объекты будут сортироваться только по категориям. Т.е. представьте таблицу "даты"-"категории". Нужно выводить то только даты, то только категории, то только те объекты, дата и категория которых совпадают.

1. Самое простое что пришло в голову хранить все объекты(юниты расхода) в одном большом списке, а информацию о дате и категории в качестве свойств объекта. Но это топорный вариант, т. к. при обращении по одному из свойств придется долго и нудно все сортировать.
2. Второе(нечто безумное) что пришло в голову. Создать **пятимерную** матрицу **год->месяц->число->массив категорий->категория**. Отображать инфу по дням тогда будет легко, но не хотелось бы лезть параллельные вселенные, а также искать категории сквозь столетия))) Еще если пользователь захочет добавить категорию, комп вообще зависнет)))
3. Еще одно (спорное) решение. Создать две структуры с указателями. В одной - все объекты отсортированы по датам(типа список пар "дата-объект"), в другой по категориям, и при отображении "за сегодня по категориям" брать конкретную дату, а потом делать выборку из каждой категории по совпадению ссылки на объект. Тогда выводить информацию отдельно по категории будет просто, по дате - сложнее.

---

Есть еще куча вариантов, можно запихать "категорию" в свойство объекта, или "дату" в свойство объекта. Короче, если одно упрощается другое - усложняется, либо использование памяти растет. Не могу найти середину) Точнее не совсем середину, дат то много, а категорий штук 20 ну +- думаю пользователь много не создаст. Базы данных типа SQL я пока не знаю, мне хотелось бы самому, а вдруг я в будущем сам базы данных писать буду))

Comment: По-моему, отличный повод узнать какую-нибудь СУБД

Comment: Оно то да) Но я сейчас пытаюсь практиковать паттерны. Но не могу, т. к. моя программа уперлась в знание БД. Даже скомпилировать не могу. Уже почти пол-года изучаю C++, но ничего кроме "совсем простенького" на нем еще не написал. Уже и С# почти выучил. Все равно ни одной программы. Я какой-то программист-теоретик!)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(текст не влез в комент)
Я бы использовал первый вариант с подобием индексов. У вас имеется большой файл со всеми расходами, пусть там хранятся записи вида дата-категория-сумма. Создаем класс-индексатор. Данный класс должен анализировать наш файл при изменении/добавлении/удалении записей. Чтобы оптимизировать процесс анализа файла, можно добавить некоторые ограничения, например: новые записи добавляются только в конец файла, это уже упростит анализ при добавлении записи до анализа только последней записи. При модификации или удалении записей тоже достаточно анализа только модифицируемой/удаляемой записи, но т.к. файл может редактироваться извне, то периодически потребуется перестройка индекса (т.е. продолжительный анализ всего файла).

Сам класс-индекс будет хранить в себе все требуемые вам данные, например: список всех годов записей, список всех категорий, список месяцев. Дополнительно можно повесить на индексы полезную нагрузку, например хранение промежуточных сумм: Имеем список всех лет с суммами расходов по каждому. Сразу легко построить отчет "затраты за год" или "среднегодовые затраты".

Дальше наш класс-индекс можно расширить по функционалу и позволить ему модифицировать файл, не нарушая целостности записей. Например, класс проанализирует файл, отсортирует все записи по датам (это займет много времени) и составит индекс "Дата - смещение в файле". Теперь при необходимости получения информации за любую дату вы сразу будете знать с какого места стоит читать файл.

Даные индексов можно сериализовать в текстовый вид и хранить рядом с самим файлом, или сделать собственный формат файла, который будет хранить всё в одном файле.

Таким образом в идеальном случае класс-индексатор будет анализировать только одну запись (добавляемую/удаляемую или модифицируемую) и перестраивать свои индексы, что значительно повысит скорость работы.

Так или иначе эту работу уже проделали за вас, создав базы данных и системы управления базами данных, которые делают нечто похожее. Для любых СУБД существуют готовые библиотеки для с++, позволяющие интегрировать их в свое приложение.